# Is the CameraX API dependent of Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-camerax

I have a question: Is the CameraX API dependent of Google Play Services? I was searching around the web, but i couldn't find anything which could give me an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 3 February 2021, I do not see any version of CameraX that depends on Play Services, based on inspecting the dependencies of the CameraX artifacts. They depend on other Jetpack libraries plus Google's edition of Guava's `ListenableFuture` library.